# AWS IAM Policy: Restrict Bucket/Folder Access By User/Role?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I'm trying to restrict Users by role to access only particular folders within an S3 bucket. The bucket is configured as "mock mountable" so to speak so that we can use it for file sharing as if it were a more traditional server. Each user is using CloudBerry to access S3 remotely.

Here's my current (broken) policy, and bucket name is "bluebolt".

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanySharedAndPAndP",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "Production and Processing/",
                    "Production and Processing/${aws:username}",
                    "Company Shared/"
                ],
                "s3:delimiter": [
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListingOfCompanyShared",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "Company Shared/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "Production and Processing/${aws:username}/",
                    "Production and Processing/${aws:username}/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsCompanyShared",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt/Company Shared/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt/Production and Processing/${aws:username}/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllS3ActionsInManagement",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt/Management/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

So, what I want to do is to restrict users to list/read/write only what is in "/Production and Processing/[UserName]", along with being able to list/read everything in "/Company Shared" while specifically prohibiting all access to "/Management" as well as everything in "/Production and Processing/*" except their user folder. Ideally a user would only see "/Company Shared" and "/Production and Processing" in bluebolt, and once they get into "/Production and Processing", they'd only see their user-named folder which is their workspace.

Right now, I am getting sporadic access by users ("You do not have permission to access") once they dig below the bluebolt top level bucket.

I don't know if this use case is common or if I'm trying to fit too-square a peg into a round hole, but any feedback/tips/similar policy applications/harsh criticism is welcome and greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your best bet is to review the bucket logs to see what the software is trying to do.  It may not be making sensible requests based on what the user is actually trying to do.  You are also, potentially, asking for trouble using spaces in key prefixes.  S3 handles them strangely, internally, for what I suspect are legacy reasons and *might* expect `"Production and Processing/"` to be `"Production+and+Processing/"` (unconfirmed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I got to work.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "*",
                    "bluebolt/Company Shared/*",
                    "bluebolt/Production and Processing/*",
                    "bluebolt/Production and Processing/${aws:userName}/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt/Production and Processing/${aws:userName}/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowCertainS3ActionsInCompanyShared",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bluebolt/Company Shared/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: is this for a user or role?

Answer (score 1):

[IAM policy variables with federated users](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-variables-federated/)

${aws:userName} policy variable will not work for roles. Use the ${aws:userID} policy variable instead of the ${aws:userName} policy variable.

${aws:userid} variable will be "ROLEID:caller-specified-name".

I used the same policy with `aws:userid` and a role.

1. Get Role ID.

   ```
   iam get-role --role-name Arsenal-role --query Role.RoleId
   AROAXXT2NJT7D3SIQN7Z6
   ```
2. Ask your users upload into `Bucket/Prefix/<RoleID:SessionName>/`

   ```
   aws s3 cp test.txt 's3://mydemo/Production and Processing/AROAXXT2NJT7D3SIQN7Z6:john/' --profile s3role
   upload: ./test.txt to s3://mydemo/Production and Processing/AROAXX2NJT7D3SIQN7Z6:john/test.txt

   aws s3 cp test.txt 's3://mydemo/Management/' --profile s3role
   upload failed: ./test.txt to s3://mydemo/Management/test.txt An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

   aws s3 cp test.txt 's3://mydemo/Production and Processing/' --profile s3role
   upload failed: ./test.txt to s3://mydemo/Production and Processing An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
   ```